# How do I convert a column to an array in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, aggregate-functions

I have a table of 2 columns, user_id and connection_type. Both the fields are not unique. One single user id can appear many times and one single connection type can appear many times. How will I group all the connection types to one single user id?

```
Table I have:

schema: 
user_id -- INT 
connection_type -- STRING

user_id connection_type 
101     4g 
102     3g 
101     4g 
101     2g 
102     2g 
101     4g 
102     4g 
101     4g 
102     4g 
101     4g

Table I need from the above:

user_id connection_type 
101     ['4g','4g','2g','4g','4g','4g'] 
102     ['3g','2g','4g','4g']
```

Comment: Show us your code so we can help.

Comment: Consider handling this in application code

Comment: doesn't appear to be anything in the data that would guarantee a particular order of elements in the array.  from the data shown, looks like `102   ['4g','2g','4g','3g']`  (the elements in a different order ) would be equally valid. (before someone says this is not an answer to the question that was asked, that's why i posted this as a *comment* and not an *answer*)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does not natively support arrays - but if you want a JSON array you can do:

```
select user_id, json_arrayagg(connection_type) connection_types
from mytable
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `group_concat` function in MySQL:

query is below:

```
select user_id,
group_concat(",",Connection_type) as connecttion_type
from table
group by user_id
```